# Markdown unnumbered section but needs anchor

Tags: markdown, r-markdown, anchor

I am working with a Markdown document where I would like to have some sections not be numbered. But I also want to create anchors for these sections. Here is an example:

```
# Appendix A: Methodology {-} {#methodology}
```

I want to have Appendix A not be numbered but I still want to link to it using the anchor.

Ideally, the solution would work for both LaTeX PDF and HTML. I have figured out how to turn off the numbered section thing [for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166555/remove-number-from-appendix) but it's not working for HTML.

Comment: Is this for HTML or PDF output?

Comment: Ideally both. I have updated the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to specify both a target name (`#...`) and a class (like `.unnumbered`) for a heading you have to use a single set of braces and the correct order. The following works for me for both HTML and PDF output:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
  pdf_document: default
---


# R Markdown

See the appendix on [methodology](#methodology).


# Appendix A: Methodology {#methodology -}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, on my `pdf_document` the tag `{#methodology -}` didn't work, but `{#methodology .unnumbered}` did.