# Is there a way to link to a tabbed section in rmarkdown?

Tags: hyperlink, r-markdown, anchor

I would like to create an internal link to a section in my rmarkdown document, but the section is a tab, and the standard linking approach doesn't seem to work.

Standard approach would be:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

# Section to link to

text and more 

# Next section

See [this section](#section-to-link-to)

Works!
```

In my case the section I want to link to is part of a tabset:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

# Section {.tabset}

## Subsection to link to

text and more 

## Next subsection

text and more

# Next section

See [this section](#subsection-to-link-to)

Doesn't work :(
```

EDIT: to be clear -- my question is not how to create a tabset, or how to create an internal link/anchor, it's the intersection:  how to create an internal link to a tabbed section.  The output should look like this:

[image: tab section with link]

I've tried some of the alternative anchor approaches (like naming the section to link to, and using that name in the link).  But no joy.  The link is highlighted in the output, suggesting it should work, but it doesn't work when clicked.

I haven't found anything that says you *can't* link a tabbed section, so I'm asking here to see if there's way, or just no way.

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to a bug that's labelled as won't fix. Not supported by design, please see the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/718).

Comment: Many thx :).  Not what I wanted to hear, but it's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53383718/13249862). If you want to link the bigger section (`Section`), you could use this: `#section`.

Code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

# Section {.tabset}

## Subsection to link to

text and more 

## Next subsection

text and more

# Next section

See [this section](#section)

This seems to work
```

To link the subsection, as you mentioned, you could use this: `[this section](#subsection-to-link-to)`.

Code:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

# Section {.tabset}

## Subsection to link to

text and more 

## Next subsection

text and more

# Next section

See [this section](#subsection-to-link-to)

This seems to work
```

Comment: The link works this way -- but I don't get the tabbed subsections in the html document anymore.  I'd like both tabbed subsections, and a way to link to one of those tabs.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the change in `.tabset`. I just changed my answer. Thanks

Comment: Using {#tabset} rather than {.tabset} as you suggest does not produce tabbed subsections in the html doc for me.  I'm working with the latest versions of all software and packages.

Comment: Sorry, I was planning to edit the answer but I got caught in another issue.